# Проверка попадания пули в коллайдер дочернего объекта через скрипт, висящий на родительном объекте

Tags: c#, unity3d

подскажите, если у меня есть скрипт персонажа, который висит на главном объекте и у меня есть дочерний объект (голова персонажа) на котором висит Collider2D, как я могу проверять попадание пули в коллайдер головы через скрипт, который висит на главном объекте? Ведь проще, когда всё в одном скрипте, а не создавать разные скрипты на все части тела для дальнейшей проверки попадания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделение ответственности это разумный путь при создание приложения. Так что создать несколько скриптов это хорошая идея.
Можно не создавать скрипт для каждой части тела (который наследуется от общего интерфейса, к примеру,IBodyPart), что вполне разумно. 
Я предлагаю создать один скрипт BodyPart. Данный скрипт мы повесим на каждую часть тела (дочерний объект игрока), будь то голова для того чтобы проходил больший урон, рука для уменьшения скорости перезарядки или нога для уменьшения скорости передвижения. В данном скрипте при попадании в объект на котором висит скрипт (OnCollisionEnter2D) мы будем вызывать событие сигнализирующее о попадании (к примеру UnityEvent HitBodyPart). Также мы будет подписывать на данное событие все что угодно, к примеру метод AplyDamage класса Player и передавать в него урон (соответственно для головы больше урона) или вызов звука попадания, воспроизведения частиц и т.д.

Что бы стало понятнее приду пример

Иерархия игрока

[image: Иерархия игрока]

Объект Player

[image: Объект Player]

```
public class Player
{
    private int _health;

    public void AplyDamage(int value)
    {
        _health -= value;
    }
}
```

Объект Head

[image: Объект Head]

```
public class BodyPart : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent HitBodyPart;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        HitBodyPart.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Чем удобен данный скрипт?! Мы можем наращивать функционал! Всё что нам необходимо это нажать у объекта части тела значок “+” и, к примеру передать объект игрок с вызовом метода ReduceSpeed описанный в скрипте Player (что замедлит игрока при попадании в данную часть тела)

P.S. Сам не считаю себя гуру программирования и отредактирую данный ответ при наличии комментариев.

Comment: Благодарю вас за детальный ответ!

Answer (score -1):

Для этого сущесвует getchild [GetChild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html)

Это должно выглядеть примерно так: `Collider  coll = this.transform.GetChild(номер).gameObject.GetComponent<Коллайдер>();`
Номер дочернего элемента считается сверху вниз(как расположен в иерархии).
Так можно получить инфу о компонентах дочерних элементов твоего игрока.Больше ничем не смогу помочь.

Comment: Крайне не рекомендую получать доступ к чему либо через GetChild. При изменении порядка дочерних элементов всё сломается, а вы даже не поймете почему.

Comment: Если всё и так сломано - не сломается.

Comment: Можно использовать `transform.Find("GameObjectName")` мы получим transform дочернего объекта с именем GameObjectName, но, опять же, все сломается если мы изменим имя объекта.