# Влияние дочернего объекта на переменные родителя?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть у меня объект gun, к которому прикреплен полигональный коллайдер, обозначающий зону обстрела. Все объекты, попавшие в эту зону, добавляются в список.

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D goal) {
    goalsList.Add(goal.gameObject);
}
```

К gun я подключил дочерний объект Visibility_Area, у которого есть своя "зона обзора" круговая (Круговой коллайдер 2D). На Visibility_Area висит скрипт, который добавляет все попавшие в триггер объекты в List.

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D goal) {
    visArea.Add(goal.gameObject);
}
```

Как этот самый лист прочитать из родительского объекта(gun), чтобы проверить одновременное нахождение в обоих зонах?
Или, может, есть другой способ передать информацию объекту gun, что какой-то объект попал в обе зоны одновременно?

Подобные вопросы уже были, но ничего из этого не смог осуществить, все равно не то.

Ребят, спасайте! Уже двое суток голову ломаю. Если как-то надо дополнить вопрос, закину нужную информацию.

Что уже опробовано:

Через      `childTrans = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0); child = childTrans.gameObject; ifGoal = child.ifGoalVis;`
я получаю объект Visibiliry_Area. Но как теперь изъять из него список? Если я обращаюсь к нему теперь, например ifGoal = child.ifGoalVis, где ifGoal - переменная типа bool в родителе, а ifGoalVis - переменная типа bool в дочернем объекте, то .ifGoalVis подчеркивает красным и пишет ""GameObject" не содержит определения "ifGoalVis", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "ifGoalVis", принимающий тип "GameObject" в качестве первого аргумента.

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1091986/467156) еще интересный способ, но я остановился в самом начале при создании UnityEvent. Он просто говорит >Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "UnityEvent" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку). [Assembly-CSharp]<

Может, когда объект попадает в дочерний коллайдер(OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll), можно отправить какое-то сообщение с указанием этого объект родителю. Что-то вроде "В меня заехал объект coll.gameObject, добавь его в свой List"? А дальше уже работать с этим списком в родителе (что было бы идеально). Так возможно?

Comment: `Transform.GetChild` - [оно](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html)?

Comment: Так я получаю объект Visibiliry_Area. Но как теперь изъять из него список? Если я обращаюсь к нему  теперь, например `ifGoal = child.ifGoalVis`, где ifGoal - переменная типа bool в родителе, а ifGoalVis - переменная типа bool в дочернем объекте, то .ifGoalVis подчеркивает красным и пишет ""GameObject" не содержит определения "ifGoalVis", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "ifGoalVis", принимающий тип "GameObject" в качестве первого аргумента.

Answer (score 0):

Это было тяжело, но я додумался:

Мы работаем с объектом Gun (на нем висит Poligon Collider 2D) и его дочерним объектом Visibility_Area (На нем висит Circle Collider 2D).
[image: Так выглядит объект]

К Gun прикреплен скрипт Attack:

```
public class Attack : MonoBehaviour {

public List<GameObject>         goalsList;      // Список объектов, которые входят в зону атаки
public List<GameObject>         visList;        // Список объектов, которые видит орудие
public List<GameObject>         visGoalList;    // Список объектов, которые видны и по которым можно стрелять 


void Awake() {
    goalsList = new List<GameObject>();         // Инициализация списка объектов, которые входят в зону атаки;
    visList = new List<GameObject>();           // Инициализация списка объектов, которые видит орудие
    visGoalList = new List<GameObject>();       // Инициализация списка объектов, которые видны и по которым можно стрелять 
}

public virtual void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D goal) {
    goalsList.Add(goal.gameObject);
    if(visList.Contains(goal.gameObject) == true) {
        visGoalList.Add(goal.gameObject);
    }
}
public virtual void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D goal) {
    goalsList.Remove(goal.gameObject);
}

// Совершить выстрел (начать обстрел)
void shot() {
    
}
```

}

В Attack я инициировал три списка, которые заполняются по мере попадания объектов в тот или иной коллайдер. Также в этом классе имеется функция, заполняющая один из списков(goalsList), заодно она проверяет, нет ли данного объекта в зоне Visibility_Area (visList). Если есть, то заполняет и третий список (visGoalList).

К Visibility_Area прикреплен скрипт Visibility_Ar:
public class Visibility_Ar : Attack {
public Attack visArea;      // Ссылка на родителя

```
public override void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D goal) {
    visArea.visList.Add(goal.gameObject);
    if(visArea.goalsList.Contains(goal.gameObject) == true) {
        visArea.visGoalList.Add(goal.gameObject);
    }
}

public override void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D goal) {
    visArea.visList.Remove(goal.gameObject);
}
```

}

Этот класс (скрипт) наследует класс Attack. В нем я создаю ссылку на родителя [image: Visibiliti_Ar в Инспекторе]. Далее, также, когда объект попадает в триггерную зону Visibility_Area, я добавляю его во второй список (visList), и проверяю, есть ли этот объект в первом списке (goalsList), чтобы добавить его в третий список (visGoalList).

Тадааааам!!! Теперь мы можем проверить два условия для стрельбы в объект в нужном секторе. Наше орудие заметило цель, и цель находится в зоне поражения.

Если все выглядит и реализовано топорно и можно это как-то модернизировать, буду рад внесению корректив.